# Unable to return promise values within jQUERY DataTables api column definitions using render function

Tags: datatables

I'm trying to call a function within the render columnDefs of my jQuery Datatables api. The data is returned in the console but using a return statement doesn't print the data on the table. There is also a data table warning that pops up before the table is rendered because it looks like no data is being returned.

However, when I use the second snippet to return 'nothing' - all is well and I don't receive the datatable warning.

How do I return the values from my promise?

```
{
    "targets": [5],
    "className": 'text-center',
    "render": function (data, type, row, meta) {
        //the if statement prevents the function from being called multiple times
        if (type === 'display') {
            //this if statement prevents undefined from being returned
            if (typeof getJSON == 'function') {
                getJSON(row.ID).then(function (val) {
                    if (val) {
                        //I see these values printed on the console for each row
                        console.log(JSON.stringify(val))
                        //but if I add return statement here data is still not printed on table
                        return JSON.stringify(val);
                    }
                    else {
                        return 'not available'
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
},
```

This works no errors:

```
{
    "targets": [5],
    "className": 'text-center',
    "render": function (data, type, row, meta) {
        return 'nothing'
    }
},
```

The promise:

```
async function getJSON(deviceID) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var data = JSON.stringify({
            'deviceID': deviceID
        });
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: MYURL,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: data,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (results) {
                resolve(results.data)
            },
            error: function (error) {
                reject(error)
            },
        })
    })
}
```

This prevents the datatable warning but no values are rendered on the table. However, the console log is still showing the values for each row. Although, I think this defeats the purpose of using a promise:

```
{
    "targets": [5],
    "className": 'text-center',
    "render": function (data, type, row, meta) {
        //declaring returnValue here prevents datatable warning.
        let returnValue = '';
        //the if statement prevents the function from being called multiple times
        if (type === 'display') {
            //this if statement prevents undefined from being returned
            if (typeof getJSON == 'function') {
                getJSON(row.ID).then(function (val) {
                    if (val) {
                        //I see these values printed on the console for each row
                        returnValue = (JSON.stringify(val))
                        console.log(returnValue)                                        
                    }
                    else {
                        returnValue = 'not available'
                    }
                });
            }
        }
        return returnValue;
    }
},
```

Comment: The DataTables `render` function - `function (data, type, row, meta) { ... }` itself needs to _return_ data to DataTables (synchronously, in this case). But an asynchronous function _within_ that DataTables function cannot return any data _outside_ of itself. That's the nature of asynchronous callbacks/promises/futures. The results of your resolved promise only exist in the context of the asynchronous call. You can see the data in the console, due to this. The only thing you can `return` to DataTables is the unresolved promise. If this is a bit mind-bending, I would not disagree.

Comment: @andrewJames That makes perfect sence. I guess I'm going to need to retrieve this data before loading the table. Not quite sure how I will handle this. Thanks.

Comment: The simple, very crude solution is to force your jQuery Ajax call to be synchronous by adding `async: false` (and removing the `async` promise). This is deprecated, but still works (I doubt it will ever be removed). Then, the DataTables render function will wait for the results to be available. Otherwise, yes, you can gather all the data you need beforehand. Someone else may know a better approach.